# Checkin feature in facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to create an application on android which implement checkin feature. I read api reference for facebook api several times already and basically I am clueless. I understand that simply I do need to issue a POST request to facebook graph api server like this one:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
 -F 'message=The coffee is just meh.' \
 -F 'place=PAGE_ID' \
 -F 'coordinates={"latitude":"...", "longitude": "..."}' \
 -F 'tags=USER_ID1, USER_ID2' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins
```

However I have no idea how to get those place[page_id] or coordinates[long and lat]. 
Question is if I have a name of place I want to check in, how could i search for its place[page_id] and how to get those coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checkins you check this links for your references

[Checkins for Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/)

1. If you want to get the Checkins of Particular user just use this API

   ```
    https://graph.facebook.com/[user id]/checkins
   ```

in these just pass the USERID of the User.

1. If you want to get the Latest checkins of particular user use this API

   https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

in these get your access token and pass it..

3 . If you are having Latitude and Longitude you can get the Nearest Locations by using this API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center="+latitude+","+longitude+"& distance=5000&
```